# Showing custom complex data class

Tags: haskell, complex-numbers

I'm just learning about *data* and I'm trying to somewhat define complex numbers with it.

So far I have the following:

```
data Complex = Complex Int Int deriving(Eq)

instance Show Complex where
    show Complex a = a -- Not working

instance Num Complex where
    Complex a b + Complex c d = Complex (a+c) (b+d)
    -- etc.
```

What I'm trying to do is to instance Show in order to make the program print a string like a complex number, such as: *"a + bi"*

I understand why the code I wrote errors, since a is of type Complex and the program expects a string, but I can't wrap my head around how I can separate both numbers and then add "i" to b, as well as put the operator inbetween.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
show Complex a = a
```

defines a function `show` with *two* arguments, the first one being `Complex` and the second one being `a`. This copes with the signature of `show` in class `Show`, where we only find one argument.

Since that argument must be a `Complex`, you probably want something like

```
show (Complex a b) = show a ++ " + " ++ show b ++ "i"
```

Note how we use `show` on `a` and `b` of type `Int` to convert them to strings, and then concatenate a bunch of strings using `++`.

Also note that when `b` is negative the output of the above is suboptimal. You might want to change the function accordingly.